# Apical dominance in plants

Tags: botany, plant-physiology

Could someone help me understand a few concepts related to apical dominance
1) why auxin is a dominant over other hormones?
2) how exactly the mechanism of apical dominance works?

Comment: Which link did your research produce, and what concept from that link is it that you don't understand?